# PHP OOP - Duplicate records entry

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, switch-statement

I have to tables in my mysql database which is ***resumes***
[image]

I'm using PHP OOP And I have this form **register.php** that user need to fill in.

My goal is to :

1. Same user can submit multiple application as long as the positions does not send twice. For example "Thomas send first application using ***thomas@mail.com***, id ***1111*** and position as ***executive*** but he cannot submit the same positions on second time using the same email address or id number"

Can anyone help ? Below is my code. *Note : I'm having a problem on ***Check.php***. Im not sure how to check in ***case 'duplicate':*** area.

**Register.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'database/connect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $filter         = new Check();
        $submission     = $filter->filterForm($_POST, array(
            'email'             => array(
                    'required'  => true,
                    'unik'      => 'resumes'
                ),
            'id_number'         => array(
                    'required'  => true,
                    'unik'      => 'resumes'
                ),
            'positions'         => array(
                    'required'  => true,
                    'duplicate' => 'resumes'
                )
        ));
        if($submission->valid()){
            $sender = new Sender();
            try{
                $sender->create(array(
                    'email'         => Input::get('email'),
                    'id_number'     => Input::get('id_number'),
                    'positions'     => Input::get('positions')
                ));
                // header to other location after success
            }catch(Exception $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach($submission->errors() as $error){
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Submit Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>email :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ID Number :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="id_number" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Position Applied :</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="positions">
                        <option>Non Executive</option>
                        <option>Executive</option>
                        <option>Management</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Application"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Check.php**

```
<?php
    class Check{
        private $_valid = false,
                $_errors = array(),
                $_db,
                $_count  = 0;
        public function __construct(){
            $this->_db = // Connection to DB using PDO
        }
        public function filterForm($source, $items = array()){
            foreach($items as $item => $rules){
                foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){

                    $inputValue = $source[$item];
                    if($rule === 'required' && empty($inputValue)){
                        $this->addError("{$item} is required");
                    } else if(!empty($inputValue)){
                        switch($rule){
                            case 'unik':
                                $checkUnik = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                                if($checkUnik->count()){
                                    $this->displayError("{$item} already exists");
                                }
                            break;
                            case 'duplicate':
                                $checkDuplicate = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                                if($checkDuplicate->count()){
                                    $checkUsers = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM resumes");
                                    if($checkUsers->count()){
                                        $this->displayError("User already apply this positions");
                                    }
                                }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(empty($this->_errors)){
                $this->_passed = true;
            }
            return $this;
        }

        public function valid(){
            return $this->_valid;
        }
        public function errors(){
            return $this->_errors;
        }
        public function displayError($error){
            $this->_errors[] = $error;
        }
        public function count(){
            return $this->_count;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Sender.php**

```
<?php
    class Sender{
        private $_db;
        public function __construct($user = null){
            $this->_db = // Connection to DB
        }
        public function create($fields = array()){
            if(!$this->_db->insert('resumes', $fields)){
                throw new Exception('You have a problem adding information.');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest adding `in addition` a compound key on those fields that is unique.  That is to say a key that takes both fields combines them and is set to unique.  This prevents errors in code from creating duplicates, and makes it impossible for a duplicate. You'll still want proper code to hide the DB errors from the end user, but it's the right thing to do... IMO.  It's good to have your application do it, but enforcing the uniqueness on the Database is the Point of Failure, or last line of defense.

Comment: code should not go 7 levels deep. youre doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, `user_id` should not be `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Instead make an `id` column that is the primary key and is `AUTO_INCREMENT` :)

Also this is really worth reading through http://www.phptherightway.com/ :)